# How do I double check my PHP signin form

Tags: php, sql

I made a signin form that will look through the database and find a match to the user's credentials, but how do I fix this code so it will relocate the page if there is no match.

```
<?php 

 session_start();

 include_once 'includes/dbh.php';

 $username = $_POST['u_name'];
 $password = $_POST['pwd'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     if ($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']) {
         $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
         header("Location: second_index.php?signinSuccessful");
     }
     if ($username != $row['username'] && $password != $row['password']) {
         header("Location: index.php?NotSucessful");
     }
 }
```

I tried putting the code inside of the loop, but I know that can't work, and if I put it outside of the loop, It redirects even if the credentials are correct. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all the users from the `users` table and checking each record manually in php.
The reason why your code doesn't work is because the `while` loop doesn't check all the users in user table. If the first record in the retrieved table data doesn't match with entered `username` and `password`, it will go to 2nd `if` block and redirect.

You should change your query to filter by user-entered values.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'username' AND PASSWORD='password'
```

And later check in php if any record is returned. If any record is returned, it is a valid user, else redirect the user to failed authentication page.

As a good practice, make sure to use parameterized query.

**Update** Replace the `while` loop and block with this.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
    // valid user
}else{ 
    // invalid user
}
```

Comment: how do I check if the record is returned using this method?

Comment: Use `if` instead of `while`

Comment: How do I use the if statement? I'm not sure how to check if  the return isn't false

Comment: Update the answer. Check it out.

Comment: I have exactly what you had, but I'm getting this error

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /srv/disk11/2452057/www/link-hub.dx.am/signin.php on line 13

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk11/2452057/www/link-hub.dx.am/signin.php:13) in /srv/disk11/2452057/www/link-hub.dx.am/signin.php on line 17

Comment: Try `mysqli_num_rows` instead of `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you and you may optionally upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is totally wrong, you're looping trough all the users to see if the user exist, instead of that sql statement try 
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where user='$user' and password='$password'";`

And to avoid any data breach in that sql statemen you have to serialize the user and pass like that before adding it to the statement

```
$user =  mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $user);
$password =mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
```

Then you only check if the fields aren't empty (which means the user exist)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need while loop in this case when you fetching data from database? Using sql and make the database fetch the only one correct answer, don't make server site do unnecessary work.
I propose just do simple fetch then if check, no need for while loop at all.
Your logic is always redirect to index.php when username password not correct so of course it will always do so when your while loop on server do not hit the correct user.